# How to get blob as Stream when using blob-triggered Isolated Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Right now, my function looks like this:

```
[Function(nameof(Functions.ProcessUpload))]
public void ProcessUpload([BlobTrigger("integration/{name}")] object blob, string name)
{           
}
```

When triggered, parameter `blob` is an instance of `System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` type - meaning, all contents of the blog are provided in memory. All the examples I saw online have the parameter as a `string`. Neither `System.ReadOnlyMemory<byte>`, nor `string` are applicable in my case, since I need to be able to work with potentially 1GB+ big blobs.

With in-process functions, the blob parameter was of type `Stream` and everything worked. How can I process newly created blobs as streams with Isolated functions?

Comment: according to the documentation tih is not possible for the moment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage

Comment: Thank you - yes, it looks like it is indeed a case. There are also multiple issues in azure-functions github related to this, all with the same answer, that this is not currently supported. I will probably just use in-processes model for a time being and hope that Streams will be at some point introduced to isolated model. Feel free to write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per August 2022, this is not supported:

- [Azure Blob storage trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#usage)

Looking at the [Guide for running C# Azure Functions in an isolated process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings), there are some interesting notes:

> Because .NET isolated projects run in a separate worker process, bindings can't take advantage of rich binding classes, such as `ICollector<T>`, `IAsyncCollector<T>`, and `CloudBlockBlob`. There's also no direct support for types inherited from underlying service SDKs, such as [DocumentClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient) and [BrokeredMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage). Instead, bindings rely on strings, arrays, and serializable types, such as plain old class objects (POCOs).